# RAML specification Traits issue

Tags: mule, raml

I get this syntax error, while I'm using the traits two times in the resource(one in the header part and another one is in the response part),I'm trying to fix it, but unable to do it.

```
error is :

     is:
           -Responsemessage
```

Hence below is the RAML specification.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: RAML_Project
traits:
  Responsemessage:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: {"Statuscode": 1,"message" :"Success done by traits "}
  client-id-required:
    headers:
      client_id:
        type: string
        required: true
      secret_key:
        required: true
        type: string
/QueryActivity:

  get:
  is:
    - client-id-required   
    queryParameters:
      Fistname:
        type: string
        required: true
    is:
       -Responsemessage     
/QuerybyEmpid:
  get:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: !include dataType.raml
    is:
      - Responsemessage
```

Comment: The indentation seems wrong. Note that it is significant in RAML.

Answer (score 2):

`-Responsemessage` is missing the space between the `-` and the `R`. Also you seem to have 2 `is:` facets in the same resource. Thie `-` is the YAML array notation. I recommend to instead use the simpler array notation with `[]` instead:

```yaml
/QueryActivity:
  get:
    is: [client-id-required, Responsemessage]
    queryParameters:
        Fistname:
          type: string
          required: true
```